# Help needed for Matlab Spectrogram plot

Tags: matlab, spectrogram

I am trying to plot a spectrogram using Matlab.
Basically what I need is to have:
-time in the X axis
-Velocity in Y axis
-Intensity is the current (in pico Ampere)

Basically, I want to create a simliar plot as the one attached here.

Time is an array of 9000 elements
Velocity is a matrix of 9000x128 elements
Current is a matrix of 9000x1280 elements

I have a thermal velocity which I can also plot which is an array of 9000 elements.

Can anyone give sugggestion on how to plot it?
I want to crate similar to the one below:

[image: Spectrogram plot example]

Answer (score 2):

spectrogram(x, N, N/2, N, fs, ‘yaxis’) is my default one liner.

To get rid of the non-SI time units, I think you need to do
[S, F, T] = spectrogram(x, N, N/2, N, fs);
pcolor(S, F, 20*log10(abs(S)));
cb = colorbar()
cb.Label.String = «some unit»;
cl = get(gca, ‘CLim’);
set(gca, ‘CLim’, cl(2)+[-40 0];

From memory. You might want to check that S is «amplitude» rather than power, and if pcolor takes S and F in this order or backwards. Also consider shading flat (if dataset is dense) or using imagesc() instead of pcolor.